# Strong factorisation conjecture for toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, toric-varieties

In [this survey](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ehacon/FlipsFlops.pdf) is remarked (see page 6 after Example 1.12) that to prove the

> **Conjecture 1.10** (Strong factorisation). Let $\phi: X \dashrightarrow Y $ be a birational map
> between two quasi-projective varieties.
> Then there is a quasi-projective variety $W$ and two birational morphisms
> $\pi: W \to X$ and $\pi': W \to Y$ which are both the composition of a sequence of blow ups of smooth centres.

it suffices to prove it in the special case of toric
varieties? Why and how the general problem can be reduced to special case for torics?